# Attributed String not showing with its attributes

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring

I have a label with a text similar to this

```
"My <link href='..here goes an url'>first</link>and <link href='...secondUrl'>second</link>
```

I've done a function that receives an array of strings where i've stored well my open and close tag with it's attributes (url) and the text inside the tags. I want to parse that text inside the tags to be underlined, with a color and to apply the link.

I did this inside the function:

```
private func setUrlAndStyleToEachLinkText(arrayOfLinks: [String], font: UIFont){
    for link in arrayOfLinks {
        var linkAsNSString = link as NSString
        if (hasHref(linkString: linkAsNSString)) {
            // Cleaning whitespaces
            linkAsNSString = linkAsNSString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") as NSString
            let closedOpenTagPosition = linkAsNSString.range(of: "'>", options: String.CompareOptions.literal)
            let hrefPosition = linkAsNSString.range(of: "href='")
            // Obtaining url from href
            hrefUrl = linkAsNSString.substring(with: NSUnionRange(NSRange(location: hrefPosition.location + hrefPosition.length, length: 0),
                                                                      NSRange(location: closedOpenTagPosition.location, length: 0)))
            // Obtaining link text to apply tap gesture
            let linkText = linkAsNSString.substring(with: NSUnionRange(NSRange(location: closedOpenTagPosition.location + closedOpenTagPosition.length, length: 0),
                                                                       NSRange(location: link.count - 8, length: 0)))
            
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
                NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: self.underlineColor,
                NSAttributedString.Key.link: hrefUrl
            ]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: linkText, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

but attributes are not showing after that. Anyone can help me?

Edit: I found the solution, i was not applying the attributes to the correct variable. Thanks to @Larme for the comment

Comment: You are transforming your strange tagged String into HTML String. But you don't initialize the `NSAttributedString` with the method to interpret the HTML Tags...

Comment: Thanks @Larme I saw it later of this post. I was not applying to the correct variable the attributes.